# how to Delete photo with text from firebase

Tags: firebase, swift4

i use firebase for upload photo,video and text. how i can add simple button for remove information from firebase (Database & Storage)
[Firebase Database Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0odC.png)

```
static func uploadDataToServer(data: Data, videoUrl: URL? = nil, ratio: CGFloat, caption: String, Location: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if let videoUrl = videoUrl {
        self.uploadVideoToFirebaseStorage(videoUrl: videoUrl, onSuccess: { (videoUrl) in
            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: data, onSuccess: { (thumbnailImageUrl) in
                sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: thumbnailImageUrl, videoUrl: videoUrl, ratio: ratio, caption: caption, Location: Location, onSuccess: onSuccess)
            })
        })

    } else {
        uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: data) { (photoUrl) in
            self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl, ratio: ratio, caption: caption, Location: Location, onSuccess: onSuccess)
        }
    }
}

static func uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, onSuccess: @escaping (_ imageUrl: String) -> Void) {
    let photoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("posts").child(photoIdString)
    storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let photoUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
            onSuccess(photoUrl)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Button most delete 3 Childs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egw0D.png)

```
@IBAction func DeletePost(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Post", message: "Are You Sure ?", preferredStyle: .alert);

  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil));

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) {(action) in


 //.............Delete From Firebase Code


    };
    alert.addAction(okAction);

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);



}
```